# selectedvalue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I binded a dropdown list, here is my code: (DataLayer)

```
        string countrySQL = "SELECT * From Country";
        string[] param = { };
        object[] paramVal = { };

        return ClassDBQuery.ExecDataReader(countrySQL, param, paramVal);

    void GetCountry()
    {
        DataTable DTcountry = new DataTable();
        DTcountry = ClassMerchant.GetCountry();

        ddlC.DataSource = DTcountry;
        ddlC.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        ddlC.DataValueField = "CountryID";
        ddlC.DataBind();
    } // end GetCountry
```

When I include the `.datavaluefield = "CountryID"` I get this message

`selectedvalue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items dropdownlist`

But when I remove the `.datavaluefield` I am getting error in other parts of my code, because instead of getting the `CountryID`, I ended up getting the `CountryName` and forcing it to convert from String to Integer.  But this code for Data Bind works fine in my registration page. How can make my Data Bind (DropDown list) to work?

Comment: i still get the same error....
if i will not bind the drop down list, how will i see the list of the countries from the database..i am using this for update page...so when, i select the id of account i want to edit the data from the database should reflect on the controls i have in my update page...right..?

Comment: your getting this erro bcz of this line... ddlC.Items.Insert(0, "Choose Country");.....remove it u can not insert item to drop down directly which binded to datasource...if u write this u always get selected value as Choose Country

Comment: I removed ddlC.Items.Insert(0, "choose country")..still get the same error...

Comment: are u setting selected value of dropdown anywhere in your program

Comment: show your table schema of country and get country method too

Answer (score 0):

Set selected value equal to NULL or any value in data source (first value) to resolve this issue.